# C# Suggestion for Data Structure

Tags: c#-4.0, data-structures

Looking for Data Structure which has below charecteristics

1. Navigate from one node to other in both directions.
2. There can be multiple parent (source) node to any node (destination node)
3. Search should be possible and efficient
4. Memory usage and performance should be efficient

This is needed for parsing the language and providing the code completion.

Comment: #2 seems to be problematic.  "There can be multiple parent node to any node".  The concept of a parent assumes a direction of inheritance.  By allowing a node to be a parent of _any_ node assumes otherwise.

Comment: Directed graph perfectly matches these requirements.

Comment: I need this to navigate from one node to another node based on the user input. I am also inclined towards using DirectedGraph. I am working on it and will update this post if it works :)